# number of transitions in mongodb table

Tags: mongodb

I am developing a small app using mongdb and c# . Input file has row contains B, K, L, T, where  B=bedroom, K=kitchen, L=living room, T=toilet i added some new columns in input file to process my queries . Queries which user would like to see is

- number of occurrences of each B/K/L/T in each day
- number of transitions from a room to another
- time that a person spends in a room
- position of a person in a specific time or interval of time

I am done with all queries except number of transitions from room to another .

My table has "RoomID", "TimeStamp", "DayId", "Transition",  each day file contains 288 rows and at every 5 minutes it changes room for example B to T to K.

I have to track how many times a person switches from one room to other in single day .

Comment: The problem is unclear to me. Whenever a user moves from one room to another, increment a counter? Or write a `RoomChangeEvent` with time stamp in some collection, done?

Comment: i think increment a counter is a good idea room change event might take some extra efforts i believe i am quite new to mongodb . But finally user want to see how many time a user changed room in a day .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a little research on mongodb i created following query to solve my problem . 
db.mytable.count( { $where: "this.RoomID != this.Transition && this.RoomID == 'B' && this.DayID == 1" } )
this query shows me number of transitions